# xsl conversion for a single data having multiple rows

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML:

```
<Job_post>
<Job_Details>
<Job_id>C_001</Job_id>
<Job_status>Filled</Job_status>
<Job_Posting_Details>
<Posting_Site>External Careers </Posting_Site>
</Job_Posting_Details>
</Job_Details>
<Job_Details>
<Job_id>Java_002</Job_id>
<Job_status>Open</Job_status>
<Job_Posting_Details>
<Posting_Site>External Careers </Posting_Site>
</Job_Posting_Details>
<Job_Posting_Details>
<Posting_Site>Internal</Posting_Site>
</Job_Posting_Details>
</Job_Details>
</Job_post>
```

I need to convert the entries in different line in the txt file like

```
Job_id~|~Job_status~|~Posting_Site~
C_001~|~Filled~|~External Careers~
Java_002~|~Open~|~External Careers~
Java_002~|~Open~|~Internal~
```

Kindly help me to with the xslt format to convert the above xml into text file.

Comment: Like the above xml data i have more then 500 data in my xml which i need to show. Some of the entry have multiple rows for a single data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="Job_post">
        <xsl:text>Job_id~|~Job_status~|~Posting_Site~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Job_Details/Job_Posting_Details">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../Job_id)" />
            <xsl:text>~|~</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../Job_status)" />
            <xsl:text>~|~</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Posting_Site)" />
            <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
Job_id~|~Job_status~|~Posting_Site~
C_001~|~Filled~|~External Careers~
Java_002~|~Open~|~External Careers~
Java_002~|~Open~|~Internal~
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try XML parsers to get the data out. There are SAX and DOM parsers available for reading XML data.